# Run two browser at the same time

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Java and was doing a Web browser call wherein I need to log in two different accounts. 
Steps:

1. Open new browser (Browser 1)
2. Login to first account
3. Open another  new browser (Browser 2) [Issue: After opening the new browser, the Browser 1 closes]
4. Login to second account
5. Return to Browser 1
6. First account web calls second account
7. Return to Browser 2, answer the call.
8. End

Is there a way to  run two different browser at the same time to do this with Selenium WebDriver?

Note:

1. I tried to this but the first browser closes, when opening a new
   browser Actual: Chrome Browser, then open new Chrome Browser (in
   incognito), but still first chrome browser closes.
2. I initiated a different driver to open the new Chrome Browser.

   ```
   public static void main (String[] args){

       WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
       driver1.manage().window().maximize();
       driver1.get(baseUrl);
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver1,30);
       String win1 = driver1.getWindowHandle();

       driver1.switchTo().window(win1);
       WebElement emailField = driver1.findElement(By.id("email"));
       emailField.sendKeys(data1);
       WebElement passField = driver1.findElement(By.id("password"));
       passField.sendKeys(data2);
       WebElement passField = driver1.findElement(By.id("loginBtn")).click();

       WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
       driver2.manage().window().maximize();
       driver2.get(baseUrl);
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver2,30);
       String win2 = driver2.getWindowHandle();

       driver2.switchTo().window(win2);
       WebElement emailField = driver2.findElement(By.id("email"));
       emailField.sendKeys(data1);
       WebElement passField = driver2.findElement(By.id("password"));
       passField.sendKeys(data2);
       WebElement passField = driver2.findElement(By.id("loginBtn")).click();

       driver1.switchTo().window(win1);
       WebElement dialField = driver1.findElement(By.id("dial"));
       dialField.sendKeys(number);
       WebElement callIcon = driver1.findElement(By.id("call")).click();

       driver2.switchTo().window(win2);
       WebElement answerIcon = driver2.findElement(By.id("answer")).click();
       Thread.sleep(3000);
       WebElement endCall = driver2.findElement(By.id("hangup")).click();

       driver1.close(); 
       driver2.close();
       driver1.quit();
       driver2.quit();
   }
   ```

Comment: You created `driver1` and `driver2`. What's `dr` then?

Comment: I think I need to change that dr to driver. Edited the code.

Comment: You can use java script to open second browser as `((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])", URL);`